# Visualizing region outlines

Tags: regions, mesh

I want to generate a picture like this, highlight its outlines, don't show extra edges.
[image]
The built-in MengerMesh will have extra edges

```
mesh = MengerMesh[2, 3];
Graphics3D[{
  {EdgeForm[], mesh},
  {Thick, MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1]}
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]
I've tried the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174746/how-to-get-the-list-of-vertices-of-each-side-of-a-convex-hull-3d-figure), It seems that it doesn't work for regions with holes.

```
Region`Mesh`MergeCells[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@MengerMesh[2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### 3.

Inspired by [chayong's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287906/125), a direct way to identify the boundary edges using `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals ``:

```
bmr = BoundaryMesh[MengerMesh[2, 3]];

boundaryedges = Pick[MeshPrimitives[bmr, 1], 
  Map[Unitize @ (1 - Max @ Abs @ #)&] @ Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 1],1];


Show[bmr, Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[3], boundaryedges}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we identify the indices of boundary edges and highlight them using `HighlightMesh`:

```
boundaryindices = Pick[MeshCellIndex[bmr, 1][[All, 2]], 
  Map[Unitize @ (1 - Max @ Abs @ #)&] @ Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 1], 1];

HighlightMesh[bmr, 
 Style[{1, boundaryindices}, Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]]]
```

[image]

#### 1.

Combine co-planar faces and plot them using `RegionPlot3D` using the option [`BoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html):

```
bdm = BoundaryMesh @ MengerMesh[2, 3];

faces = MapApply[RegionUnion] @
   Gather[MeshPrimitives[bdm, 2], 
    CoplanarPoints[Join[First @ #, First @ #2]] &];
 
RegionPlot3D[Evaluate @ faces, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
   (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][5/3
      SquaredEuclideanDistance[{#, #2, #3}, {1, 1, 1}/2]] &)]
```

[image]

Remove the options `ViewProjection`,`ColorFunctionScaling` and `ColorFunction` to get

[image]

#### 2.

Get [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) function for `MengerMesh[2,3]` and use it with `RegionPlot3D`:

```
rmf = RegionMember @ MengerMesh[2, 3]; 

RegionPlot3D[rmf @ {x, y, z},
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 Mesh -> None, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Note that, unlike the first method above, this method fails to style the interior edges.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated**
`BoundaryMesh` is not needed, faster than the previous version

```
mesh = MengerMesh[4, 3];
idx = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8};
outlines = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 3][[All, 1, idx]] //
    RightComposition[
     ArrayReshape[#, {Times @@ Dimensions@#/6, 2, 3}] &,
     Map[Sort],
     Tally,
     Cases[{x_, 1} :> x],
     Developer`ToPackedArray,
     Line
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming

Graphics3D[{
  {EdgeForm[], mesh},
  {Black, Tube[outlines, Scaled[1/1000]]}
  }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800, Lighting -> "Classic"]
```

> {3.31279, Null}
> [image]

---

Using method in [Extract 2D quad mesh from 3D hexahedral mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271123/2090), add some optimization

```
Clear[boundaryMeshOutlines];
boundaryMeshOutlines[bmr_BoundaryMeshRegion, tol_ : 0.] :=
  Module[{enormal, graph, edges, vl, adj, corneredges},
   enormal = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 2];
   graph = MeshConnectivityGraph[bmr, {1, 2}];
   edges = MeshCellIndex[bmr, 1];
   vl = VertexList[graph];
   adj = Lookup[AssociationThread[vl, Extract[vl, 
    List/@ AdjacencyMatrix[graph]["AdjacencyLists"]]], edges][[All, All, 2]];
   corneredges = Pick[edges, UnitStep[(Dot @@ enormal[[#]] & /@ adj) - 1 + tol], 0];
   MeshPrimitives[bmr, corneredges, "Multicells" -> True]
   ];

bmesh = BoundaryMesh[MengerMesh[3, 3]];
outlines = boundaryMeshOutlines[bmesh]; // AbsoluteTiming
Graphics3D[{
  {EdgeForm[], bmesh},
  {Black, Tube[#, Scaled[1/800]] & /@ outlines}
  }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

> {0.30785, Null}
> [image]

It also works for this [Construct a polyhedron from the coordinates of its vertices and calculate the area of each face](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235524/2090)

```
q={{-10.,-7.5,-6.25},{-10.,-7.5,6.25},{-10.,0.,-10.},{-10.,0.,10.},{-10.,7.5,-6.25},{-10.,7.5,6.25},{-1.66667,-11.6667,-8.33333},{-1.66667,-11.6667,8.33333},{2.5,-13.75,0.},{-2.5,0.,-13.75},{1.66667,-8.33333,-11.6667},{-2.5,0.,13.75},{1.66667,-8.33333,11.6667},{-1.66667,11.6667,-8.33333},{1.66667,8.33333,-11.6667},{-1.66667,11.6667,8.33333},{1.66667,8.33333,11.6667},{2.5,13.75,0.},{10.,-10.,0.},{10.,-6.25,-7.5},{10.,-6.25,7.5},{10.,6.25,-7.5},{10.,6.25,7.5},{10.,10.,0.}};

bdm=BoundaryMesh@DelaunayMesh[q];

Graphics3D[{
  {EdgeForm[], bdm},
  {Black, 
   Tube[#, Scaled[1/800]] & /@ boundaryMeshOutlines[bdm, 10^-5.]}
  }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: How long do you get the output?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Less than 4 seconds in total.